# The way to prove that nested closed intervals are not empty

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkKfRaI-cqs

Nested: If $m>n$, $a \le a_m \le b_m \le b_n$

At 1:12:00 the professor claimed that $x\ge a_i$ and $x\le b_i$ where $x=\sup{a_i}$

But I think maybe we shall further prove $x$ does not equal to $b_i$ since the inequality proved here is not strict.

Comment: You should learn to use mathjax. I introduced math markup for now, look at it!

Comment: Thank you! But I bet it'll take me a long time to learn it!

Comment: No, the basics are rather simple! I learned the basics of $\TeX$ (mathjax is inspired by TeX) a looong time ago, from the TeXBook (D Knuth) in about 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't watch the video you linked, but you're right that it's necessary to show $x$ doesn't exceed any of the $b_{i}$. Luckily, that's easy by applying the same type of argument "from above": If $y = \inf b_{i}$, you have
$$
a_{n} \leq a_{m} \leq x \leq y \leq b_{m} \leq b_{n}
  \quad\text{for all $n < m$.}
$$
(Be sure you can justify each inequality *using the definitions* of sup and inf.)

Comment: Could you please have a look at the lecturer's proof? it's quite the same as the way you did. And I think this extra step is needed like you said.

Comment: I'm afraid not (about the video). If it helps, you can also argue that each $b_{i}$ is an upper bound for _all_ the $a_{i}$ (clear), and therefore an upper bound for their supremum $x$ (by definition), without considering the infimum of the $b_{i}$.

Comment: "and therefore an upper bound for their supremum" what's the logic here?

Comment: If $A$ is a set of real numbers (such as the collection of all the $a_{i}$), a _supremum_ of $A$ is a real number $x$ satisfying two conditions: $a \leq x$ for all $a$ in $A$, and $x \leq M$ for every upper bound $M$ of $A$. Here, each $b_{i}$ is an upper bound of $A$. :)